# Spring: request body missing error when sent from client but works with postman?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Rest backend setup as well as a react client. Both are setup on different local ports. I am trying to send a simple request from my React client using a fetch call to my spring rest api.

When sending the POST request using Postman, the API responds as expected.

When sending the request from the React client I receive the following 400 error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Required request body is missing: public 
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>
```

I have done the following:

1. Disabled CSRF on my spring application.
2. Set global CORS config to accept all requests.
3. Ensured on multiple occasions that the request body is correct and identical to that sent via Postman.

Here is my Fetch request from react client:

```
fetch(API_BASE_URL + '/api/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST'
        }),
        body: {
            username: this.state.uname,
            password: this.state.password,
        }
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                    response.status);
                return;
            }

            // Examine the text in the response
            response.json().then(function (data) {
                let json = JSON.parse(data);
                let token = json.tokenType + " " + json.accessToken;
                localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
                alert('successfully saved token:' + token);
            });
        }
    )
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those interested:

The data passed in payload was of an incorrect format. While this may not appear logical, creating a variable as so:

```
let payload = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
    };
```

And passing that as the body to fetch seems to work.

Hopefully this may help others facing the same problem..